# behavior of is.integer() in re-assignments

Tags: r

Let's create an integer vector and assign an integer value to its 1st element and re-assign it to a non-integer.

```
> int = integer(0)
> int[1]
> NA
> is.integer(int)
[1] TRUE

# assign int[1] to an integer
> int[1] = 1L
> is.integer(int)
[1] TRUE
# Now, re-assign to a non-integer
> int[1] = 1
> is.integer(int)
[1] FALSE # as expected
```

Now, let's do the same but in reverse order, i.e. assign an non-integer first, then re-assign to an integer.

```
# try again assigning to a non-integer first
> int = integer(0)
> int[1] = 1
> is.integer(int)
[1] FALSE
# Now, assigning to integer
> int[1] = 1L
> is.integer(int)
[1] FALSE # why?
```

Does the type of the last evaluation depend on the previous assignment?

Comment: (+1) for this question, learned quite a lot from it

Comment: Dang, they come out of the woodwork for these types of questions! +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would have phrased the behavior you're seeing a little differently:

```
x <- 1:2
> storage.mode(x)
[1] "integer"
> x <- x + 0.5
> storage.mode(x)
[1] "double"
> x
[1] 1.5 2.5
> storage.mode(x) <- "integer"
> x
[1] 1 2
```

In general, asking R to convert things *back* to an integer would risk a loss of information. So once an assignment forces a conversion to double, there's no going back unless you explicitly request it (and that's a good thing).

The specific example you chose relied on there being only a single value, but R doesn't really have a scalar type, so everything has to think in terms of vectors. This means that many R operations have to be aware of the possible effects things will have on whole vectors of values.

Comment: (+1) I didn't know that, but I was suspecting this :)

Comment: I'd highly recommend using `typeof()` instead of `storage.mode()` (unless you're striving for S compatibility)

Comment: @hadley I specifically chose storage.mode because it had an assignment method and I wanted to demonstrate the loss when converting double to integer. Is there another more idiomatic way of setting the internal storage mode?

Comment: So, for vectors of length = 1, storage.mode(int[1]) <- "integer" doesn't work, but storage.mode(int) <- "integer" does!

Comment: Also is.integer(as.integer(int[1])) returns TRUE, but not if you assign first then make the test: int[1] = as.integer(int[1]); is.integer(int[1]) is FALSE

Comment: OF course, I'm talking about the case in which you first create int <- integer(0); int[1] <- 1.

Comment: @aguiar Right. R is vector based. You won't be able to have different storage modes within a single (atomic) vector. Lists will holds objects of different types. You will never be able to turn a double vector into an integer vector (or alter any of the elements mode) without explicitly coercing the whole vector as I showed.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Don't want to be insistent, but why is.integer(as.integer(int[1])) is TRUE?

Comment: That extracts (copies) the value and coerces it to integer. So it is no longer the same object that is stored in int[1].

Comment: @joran oh I see - I usually also avoid the setter version of those functions because I think they're confusing. They don't modify an existing object, but instead must create a new one.

Answer (score 3):

> Does the type of the last evaluation depend on the previous assignment?

No. `int[1] = 1` implicitly coerces `int` from integer to numeric since you assigned a numeric value to an element of an integer vector.

In the example below, R will not implicitly coerce `num` from numeric to integer because that could cause data loss... and always checking if you can safely cast a numeric vector to an integer is not efficient.

```
num <- numeric(0)
num[1] <- 1L
```

Answer (score 2):

If you had wanted `is.integer` to return what you expected, you would have needed to do some action that coerced that numeric (== 8 byte type)  to integer mode (4 byte type). Assignment of an integer value to a numeric vector would not be expected to require coercion. Same thing would happen if assigning a logical to an empty integer :

```
> int = integer(0)
>  int[1]
[1] NA
> int[1] <- FALSE
> int
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 1):

From `?is.integer`,

> `is.integer` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether its argument is of integer `type` or not, unless it is a factor when it returns `FALSE`.

Putting this to the test, we can see *why* `is.integer` is returning `FALSE`

```
> int <- integer(0)
> int[1] <- 1
> typeof(int)
# [1] "double"
> int[1] <- 1L
> typeof(int)
# [1] "double"
```